# How to Retrieve/Save a BLOB from MySQL Database using R?

Tags: mysql, r, database, blob, dbi

I have implemented a R Shiny application in which I upload successfully a xgb.model binary file into MySQL Database and after that I would also like to retrieve/save it in the local storage in order to use the xgb.load() and create a prediction.

Below you can find the details:

**Database Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE savedmodels (
  sub VARCHAR(255),
  modeltype_id INTEGER,
  dataset_id INTEGER,
  depended_var VARCHAR(255),
  last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  uploaded_model LONGBLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY (modeltype_id, dataset_id, depended_var),
  FOREIGN KEY (sub) REFERENCES users(sub),
  FOREIGN KEY (dataset_id) REFERENCES uploadedfiles(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (modeltype_id) REFERENCES modeltypes(id)
) ;
```

**BLOB Selecting Function:**

```
getModelFile <-function(sub, dataset_id, modeltype_id, depended_var){
  
  dbcon <- DBI::dbConnect(
    RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = options()$mysql$databaseName,
    host = options()$mysql$host,
    port = options()$mysql$port,
    user = options()$mysql$user,
    password = options()$mysql$password
  )
  
  query <- paste0("SELECT uploaded_model FROM savedmodels WHERE sub = '",sub, "' 
                  AND dataset_id = '",dataset_id, "' AND modeltype_id = '",modeltype_id,"' AND depended_var = '",depended_var, "';")
  
  request <- DBI::dbGetQuery(dbcon, query)
  
  
  DBI::dbDisconnect(dbcon)
  
  return(request)
  
}
```

I have tried to manage the BLOB using the getModelFIle() function, but I didn't make it since I get only the first word of the file ("binf").

Could anyone please help me to save the blob file in my local storage?

Comment: It might be better if you could make this a bit more reproducible and consistent: (1) `getModel` versus `getModelFile`; (2) we have no sample xgb model, but really we just need a simple blob, perhaps we can read in a simple png or such.

Comment: FYI, you may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).